# is there a proper way to shut down from single user mode

Tags: systemd, boot, init

I've found a lot of inconsistent documentation on single user mode.  I don't need to use it often, but I get curious, and I remember not being to use shut down commands in single user mode and pressing the reset button.  Is there a better way to leave single user mode after resetting passwords?

Comment: Single mode is not a well-defined concept, you should tell people which init and sevice management system you're using. Usually for systemd systems, systemctl poweroff still works fine.

Comment: If all else fails, you can try the old `init 0`.

Comment: Ok that explains my confusion.  I've booted into it on a few differant machines with differant distros and even an old mac.  I didn't intend this to be specific question.  I think I had an error when I tried `systemctl poweroff`, but maybe that was on the macpro..

Answer (score 0):

What do you have running in single user mode? Are databases running etc. etc. If you are worried then I would run

```
sync
```

then

```
shutdown -i 0  (though depends on what flavor you are using)
```

Comment: This is mostly an idle curiousty.  The only reason I know about single user mode is because I had to reset a password on an ~2003 macpro that somebody donated.

Answer (score 0):

For newer Linux systems, this command should work:

```
systemctl poweroff --force --force
```

Comment: It “should work”?  The power switch *will* (probably) *work* and is probably quicker, and another answer has already been presented.  Is your answer better? … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.